# How to convert custom blogs dynamic URL to static URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using `https://example.com/post?id=post_name` in my custom blog built with PHP and I want to use `https://example.com/post_name` instead.

But I also use `http://example.com/deal?id=deal_name` for displaying online shopping deals and I also want to change that to `http://example.com/deal_name`.

How do I do it? My current .htaccess file is this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want because you want to rewrite URLs to two different pages so you need to differentiate one type of URL from the other.

For example you could use `https://example.com/posts/post_name` for the post URLs and `http://example.com/deals/deal_name` for deals, you can do this adding the following rules before the current rules of your .htaccess file (just after `RewriteEngine On`):

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(.+)$ /post?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^deals/(.+)$ /deal?id=$1 [NC]
```

Another option is if `post_name` and `deal_name` have always a token that differentiate both types, for example if `post_name` starts always with `p-` and `deal_name` starst always with `d-` you could use:

```
RewriteRule ^p-(.+)$ /post?id=p-$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^d-(.+)$ /deal?id=d-$1 [NC]
```